# How to fix js code on if then statement with number Input

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button

I wanted the user to input a number and if the number is a multiple of 3 or 5, I want a word/paragraph that says, "You are a witch"

created a function but I cannot seem to make it work

```
var x;

function pop() {
  for (x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
    if (x % 3 == 0) {
      document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = 'You are a Warrior';
    } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
      document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = 'You are a wizard';
    } else if (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) {
      document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = 'You are a Sage';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = 'invalid';
    }
}
```

```
<input type="number" id="x">
<br>
<br>
<center><button onclick="pop()">Click Me</button> </center>  
<br>
<br>
<p id="onClick"></p>
```

Comment: check `if (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) ` first

Comment: Get rid of the loop. Just set x to the contents of the text box.

Comment: by the way, your code does not accept input from a user, it loops 100 times overwriting a single elements content every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never read the user input. You have a loop where there should not be one. You need to change the order of the comparisons.

```js
function pop(){
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    
    if (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = "You are a Sage";
    }
    else if (x % 3 == 0 ) {
        document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = "You are a Warrior";
    }
    else if (x % 5 == 0){
        document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = "You are a wizard";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('onClick').innerHTML = "invalid";
    } 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="x">
<br>
<br>
<center><button onclick="pop()">Click Me</button> </center>  
<br>
<br>
<p id="onClick"></p>
```